# How/From where value of AVAsset's property 'preferredVolume' get populated?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

AVAsset has a property named 'preferredVolume'. I want to know that from where and how this value get populated in an asset?

I could find nothing on google.

Comment: It's a get only property. Do you want to set it?

Comment: i dont want to set it. But i want to know who sets it or from where value gets populated?